# How do I display MJPEG stream in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, mjpeg

I have a video stream that comes as MJPEG over HTTP.

I tried to use MjpegProcessor using https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder link.

As per the instructions provided I have referenced MjpegProcessor.winmd dll in my project. But it seems that FrameReady event doesn't have Bitmap/BitmapImage member. What I am doing wrong? Is their any other way to stream MJPEG in UWP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there is no `Bitmap/BitmapImage` in `FrameReadyEventArgs` in UWP. In UWP apps, we should use `FrameBuffer` property like following:

```
private async void mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream ms = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await ms.WriteAsync(e.FrameBuffer);
        ms.Seek(0);

        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
        await bmp.SetSourceAsync(ms);

        //image is the Image control in XAML
        image.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. The code doesn't give any error, but still isn't displaying anything.